# Junit @ Test method, Giving input at runtime

Tags: java, junit

method written in my class

```
public static Advertisement[] createAd() throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    Advertisement[] ad = new Advertisement[5];
    int count =0;
    char ch;
    do
    {
    System.out.println("Enter advertisement id:");
    int id=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter advertisement type:");
    String type=br.readLine();
    ad[count]= new Advertisement(id, type);
    count++;
    System.out.println("Do you want publish another   advertisement(Y/N):");
     ch = br.readLine().charAt(0);

    if((ch!='y')&&(ch!='Y'))
    {
        break;
    }

    }while(count<=5);
    if(count==5)
    {
        System.out.println("Maximum ads reached");
        return ad;
    }
    return ad;
}


Juint @Test method
 @Test
public void testCreateAd() throws IOException
{
    Advertisement[] a = Advertisement.createAd();
    assertTrue("Maximum five ads only should be created",(a.length<=5));
}
```

I want to check, createAd method should return max of 5 object of the type Advertisement. But when @Test method is running it's asking input, can we pass input to those readLine method through some where

Comment: The thing to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416591/1531124 . Thing is: you *can* test code that reads from System.in using some tricks. But: you shouldn't do so. You completely *hide* the fact that your code is normally reading from stdin from your production code. So that it works with *any* kind of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to mock the buffered reader.
you can pass it as a method parameter (or create another method that accept it as parameter, and then Mock it in you test code.
have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371379/mocking-java-inputstream).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: it does mean that you solved? If so, please write the solution, or mark the right response as solution, for next users.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` should be a `private` class member. If you do this you can `@Mock` this member in you testclass and then you can control every call of it and the returning values.

```
@Mock
private BufferedReader bufferedReaderMock;

Mockito.doReturn("some input").when(bufferedReaderMock).readLine();
```

Now you can control and simulate values a user maybe entered.
don´t forget this before yoz´re asserting:

```
Mockito.verify(bufferedReaderMock).readLine(); // Verify it was called
Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(<all mocks)); // verify no other dependency class/member was called.
```

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: yes.. I used another way to get the same..

Comment: Maybe post it as command so others can use your was, too.

Comment: @Rule
  public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock    = emptyStandardInputStream();@Test
 public void testCreateAdLength() throws IOException
 {
  
  systemInMock.provideLines("3","1", "social","2","media","3","laptop");
     assertTrue("Length of an array should be checked", Advertisement.createAd().length==3);
  
 }

Comment: used system-rules-1.16.0.jar