# How to mock System.in in Java (except using inside Junit Test Case)?

Tags: java, mocking, inputstream

I have used TextFromStandardInputStream with JUnit Test Case, which works fine. But now I want to mock StandardInputStream outside Test Cases for my requirements. I have used the same TextFromStandardInputStream outside the Test Case but it didn't work at all. So, is there any way to do the work done?

> Sample of StandardInputStream with Test Case that I have used

```
@Rule
public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = emptyStandardInputStream();
```

Inside Test Case :

```
systemInMock.provideLines("1","2");
```

Comment: Java doesn't have a `StandardInputStream` class. Did you mean you want to mock `System.in`? If so, edit the question and clarify your terminology.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking Java InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6371379/5221149)

Comment: Andreas, thanks for suggestion. Already edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could set system in to your mock by using `System.setIn()`, assuming you've stubbed your input stream:

```
System.setIn(systemInMock);
```

This works with a normal input stream:

```
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("yes".getBytes()));
System.out.println(System.in.read());// outputs 121
```

Likewise, you can reset it if you stored it in a variable before setting `System.in` to the value of the mock.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Aspect Oriented Programming` to intercept to `System.in` and do mocking instead of calling real `System.in`. `AspectJ` or `Spring AOP` might be a starting point.