# Junit Test for InputStreamReader with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Can you please help me in writing the Junit test case for the below code?

```
public class ConsoleReader implements InputReader {
    public Cell readInput() {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter the co-ordinate Seperated by Comma");
            String coOrdinates = reader.readLine();
            String[] values=coOrdinates.split("\\,");
            return new Cell(Integer.parseInt(values[0]),Integer.parseInt(values[1]));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Insteed of `new InputStreamReader(System.in)` pass `System.in` as method argument so you will be able to actually push data into the stream.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking Java InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371379/mocking-java-inputstream)

Comment: as  Antoniossss has suggested the best solution (even from design perspective). if you dont like that solution , there is a tricky/dirty solution. use the System.setIn and set a mock inputstream , once your test case is executed restore the system.in using the same method. this will work only in environment you dont have securitymanger or you have permission to setIO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mockito to mock the BufferedReader, like the example below.

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = Mockito.mock(BufferedReader.class);
Mockito.when(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn("1", "2", "3");
// You can mock the result based on the type of result you are expecting.
```

Comment: But he must pass that mock first.

Answer (score 3):

1. Extract the `reader` as a field. (You can initiaize it either directly or in constructor)

   ```
   private final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   ```
2. Define a getter (either `public` or `protected`)

   ```
   protected BufferedReader getReader(){
       return reader;
   }
   ```
3. Remove initialization of `new BufferedReader(...)` from your method. Retrieve it using `getReader()` instead.

   ```
   public Cell readInput() {
       try {
           System.out.print("Enter the co-ordinate Seperated by Comma");
           String coOrdinates = getReader().readLine();
           String[] values=coOrdinates.split("\\,");
           return new Cell(Integer.parseInt(values[0]),Integer.parseInt(values[1]));
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
           ioe.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```
4. In your test class initialize your `ConsoleReader` as `Mockito.spy`

   ```
   ConsoleReader consoleReader = spy(new ConsoleReader());
   ```
5. Mock your getter

   ```
   private BufferedReader bufferedReader = mock(BufferedReader.class);

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
       doReturn(bufferedReader).when(consoleReader).getReader();
       doCallRealMethod().when(consoleReader).readInput();
   }
   ```
6. Define your test:

   ```
   @Test
   public void testReadInput() {
       when(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn("123,456");

       Cell expectedCell = new Cell(123, 456);
       Cell actualCell = consoleReader.readInput();

       assertEquals(expectedCell, actualCell);   
   }
   ```